# How can i open a file in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream

I'm using visual studio and having problem opening this text file I've put it in the folder with all the source code yet i get an "No such file or directory" error. Here's my code

```
void Game::load_map(const char *filename)
{
    int width,height,current;
    std::ifstream in(filename);
    if(in.fail()){
        std::cout << "problem opening the file" <<std::endl;
        perror(filename);
    }
    else
    {
        in >> width;
        in >> height;
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            std::vector<int> vec;
            for(int j = 0; j<width;j++)
            {
                if(in.eof())
                {
                    std::cout<< "file ends error" << std::endl;;
                    return;
                }
                in >> current;
                if(current>=0 && current<=1)
                {
                    vec.push_back(current);
                }else{
                    vec.push_back(0);
                }
            }
            map.push_back(vec);
        }
    }
    in.close();
}
```

and this how I'm calling this function:

```
load_map("map.map");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You program probably doesn't run in the same directory where the source code is placed, but rather in the `Solution\Debug` directory.

Either pass a file path relative to this directory to your function

```
load_map("..\\Project\\map.map");
```

or move the file you want to open there. Or 3rd option if you're not sure where you program's working directory is, provide a full path

```
load_map("c:\\Blah\\Blub\\Project\\map.map");
```

Comment: If the file is in the output directory you can also change the Working Directory in the Debugging section to `$(OutDir)` instead of the default `$(ProjectDir)`

Comment: i copied my file to the debug folder, yet getting the same error

Comment: @Utsav, Check where your program actually runs from the property settings, and place your file there, or try specifying a full path: `load_map("c:\\Blah\\Blub\\Project\\map.map");`

Comment: Open a file, with no path, write a sentence to it, close it.  Search for the file.  This will show you where the default directory or folder is.

Comment: If this is Visual Studio unless you changed the default the folder containing the project file should be where the file is written.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There's the `Debug` folder in the Solution, that's used rather than the projects `Debug` folder of the project as the working directory for debugging. May be there lies OP's confusion.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks alot, apparently file is made in the source code folder itself and that where my file was, yet the program was giving the error.. so i wrote the contents into the file from the program itself.. i had to load a game map so didn't really matter.. then when i tried opening that file it was successfully opened. I still can't figure out what the actual error was but the problem is solved now.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ : Creating a file is a simple experiment that always works.  I use soo many compilers that I often forget where the default directory is in Visual Studio.  This is a technique I use.  Fast.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews _"I use soo many compilers ..."_ You meant build systems/IDE's. Sure it's a good test.